# FadeIn with JQuery when clicking the li element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I can't understand why my code isn't working:

I'm using PHP to switch between my pages with a variable $main and I want this to fadeIn with JQuery. Could anyone help me out here.

```
<?php
    if (isset ($_GET['main'])) {
        $main = $_GET['main'];
    } else {
        $main = "forside";
    }
?>
...
<nav class="navigation">
    <div class="parent">
        <ul>
            <li> 
                <a href='?main=forside'> Forside </a>
            </li>
            <li> 
                <a href='?main=omos'> Om os </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href='?main=musikere'> Musikere </a>
            </li>                   
            <li> 
                <a href='?main=galleri'> Galleri </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href='?main=kontakt'> Kontakt </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
...
<div class="dynamicDiv">
    <?php include
        'case.php';
    ?>
</div>
```

So what I'm trying to do is to select my link a, and then fadeIn the new content, for each subject, in the dynamicDiv div.

Right now I'm trying with this JQuery code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".parent ul li a").click(function(){
            $(".dynamicDiv").hide();
            $(".dynamicDiv").fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone help me out here, please (:

UPDATE: Here is the case.php-file:

```
<?php
    switch ($main) {
        case 'forside': 
            include 'forside.php'; 
        break;
        case 'omos': 
            include 'omos.php';
        break;
        case 'musikere':
            include 'musikere.php';
        break;
        case 'galleri':
            include 'galleri.php';
        break;
        case 'kontakt':
            include 'kontakt.php';
        break;
        default: 
            include 'forside.php';
        break;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Nope, that isn't working :(

Comment: Where is the value of `$main` declared? You have to remember that PHP is a server-side language and JS is a client-side language. You can't pass the `$main` value into the PHP function in `case.php` once the page is loaded, unless you're doing AJAX.

Comment: Before you click on any `a` element, Is the `.dynamicDiv` empty? or it has some contents?

Comment: @ABFORCE : The content is the file forside.php before you click on any 'a'element

Comment: @Keblovszki Is it visible at all before clicking on the `a`?

Comment: @ABFORCE: Yes it is (:

Comment: The problem is that PHP is executed on the server side, and the HTML output being sent to the user (client) which JS will work. In your example, there is no way that JS can communicate with your server and say "hey, I'm changing `$main` and would like to load, for example `omos.php`", except when using AJAX. Here is a way to learn to distinction between client-side and server-side languages: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest taking a different approach because you have links that point to some were on the same page.

You can use ajax **$post** to run the PHP scripts to echo back the HTML you like to fade in

**Here is a basic demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/xfhg80mp/

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <div class="parent">
        <ul>
            <li data-id="forside"> 
                <a href="#"> Forside </a>
            </li>
            <li data-id="omos"> 
                <a href='#'> Om os </a>
            </li>
            <li data-id="musikere">
                <a href='#'> Musikere </a>
            </li>                   
            <li data-id="galleri"> 
                <a href='#'> Galleri </a>
            </li>
            <li data-id="kontakt">
                <a href='#'> Kontakt </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**Jquery**

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".parent ul").on('click', '>li', function(){

                 $(".dynamicDiv").hide();

                 $( ".dynamicDiv" ).empty();

                 var id  = $(this).closest("li").attr('data-id'); 


    /// using post to your PHP file, (echo the data) you may need to change your PHP files to echo the data at the end of it. example down below

    if (id == "forside") {

    $.post( "forside.php", function( data ) {

         $( ".dynamicDiv" ).html( data );

         $(".dynamicDiv").fadeIn(1000);
    });

    }

    /// do the same for all your other choices like above eg omos, musikere


 });


            });
```

**In your PHP files as an example** forside.php

```
<?php

$data = "Hello this is the new Information i like to show";

echo $data;

?>
```

and delete whats inside dynamicDiv and have it like this

```
<div class="dynamicDiv">

</div>
```

[image]

[image]

```
<?php

$data = "<h1>Hello this is the new Information i like to show</h1><br><img height='100' width='100' src='dfd.jpg' >";

echo $data;

?>
```

[image]

Comment: Well it do the alert and prints my data-id, but how do I get the content inside the dynamicDiv to hide and fadeIn with the new content?

Comment: Ok so you are trying to post to the same page and run (forside.php,,,, etc). That's not going to work. What you need to do is when you grad the id from my example run the relevant php script to echo the data using ajax and put the data in the (<div class="dynamicDiv">) so you can fade it in. Let me try and update my answer to better explain. I cant do a demo for you as fiddle doesn't like PHP directly in unsless you have a link

Comment: I don't have a link to my code so a fiddle would be great. Thank you very much

Comment: See my updated answer using ajax to post to PHP and get info back

Comment: Hmm.. I can't get this to work. If I do it there aren't any content on the different sites.

Comment: Sorry you need to put a (#) in the links. i just updated the question. I gave it a test on my server and it works. Without the (#) in the links it refreshes the page

Comment: Yeah, it works with the #, but how to you get the images and divs in the $data variables that should be echo'ed?

Comment: in your PHP files construct your $data as HTML. eg ($data ="<p>New Info</p><img src='myimage.jpg' /> etc etc etc")

Comment: Thank you soooo much! This is working so fine (: You are an angel! Thank you, thank you.

Comment: Basically the reason @Tasos suggested using php AJAX post approach :: the page is being loaded up in browser is actually client-side scripting, meanwhile php is server-sided.  The server has no way of knowing which url is being clicked in order for server to render the desired result.  Bridge is being established between browser and server is by this approach of using AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.preventDefault()` and inorder to change text dynamically inside div try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".parent ul li a").click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();   //Prevent Page from redirecting.
         $(".dynamicDiv").text($(this).text());
         $(".dynamicDiv").hide();
         $(".dynamicDiv").fadeIn(1000);
     });
 });
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tmdef9wa/)

Comment: I agree this is necessary to prevent the page from redirecting but it won't change the 'dynamic content'

Comment: Well, like @andrew said, it prevent the page from redirect, but the dinamicDiv content is the same when clicking the link (.parent ul li a). But it do hide and fadeIn at the same page :/ How do one switch page and hide and fadeIn (: ?

Comment: @Keblovszki...sorry but i didn't getting you..if page will not redirect then hide and fade will be on same page only...sorry can you explain a bit more????

Comment: @kartikeya: Yes I can. When I click at my navigation menu with this new preventDefault then the content will be the same no matter what (.parent ul li a) I'm clicking. Does it make sense?

Comment: @Kartikeya: I want to fadeIn the content of a given (.parent ul li a) in the div-element dynamicDiv. With your answer I just faded in the same content for every (.parent ul li a). I don't know how to explain it better so I really hope that I explained it good enough (:

Comment: @Kartikeya: Sorry, it isn't that. I try again :D and thank you for your patience.
Look, when clicking at the link 'a' I want the content in my files in the case.php to fadeIn in the dynamicDiv div-element.

Comment: @Keblovszki...first of all just update the question because it is very unclear and sorry i think in your question there is little bit php stuff besides jquery and i dont know php much but i m glad that atleast my event. preventDefault worked for you.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/a3wxp3p5/1/)

```
    $('nav a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        b = $(this).attr('href')
        //console.log(b)
        var a = myFunction(b)
        $(".dynamicDiv").hide();
        $('.dynamicDiv').html(a);
        $(".dynamicDiv").fadeIn(1000);
    });

    function myFunction(a) {
        switch (a) {
            case 'one':
                day = "Sunday";
                return day;
                break;
            case 'two':
                day = "tuesday";
                return day;
                break;
            case 'three':
                day = "wednesday";
                return day;
                break;

            case 'four':
                day = "thruday";
                return day;
                break;

        }
    }
```